# DevExpress Web designer JSONDataSource structure

Tags: devexpress

I have a cloud accounting system, and I am trying to use devex web designer to design and print invoices.

Using a JSONDataSource I managed to design my report but some information does not appear where it should be.

For example, sending the payments list, would be expected to display a table in the "Details" section, but it only displays the first row.

Here are examples I tried to format my json source:

1st attempt:
`{ "header": {"client_name": "x"}, "data": [ { "item": "x", "price": 10 }, {  "item": "y", "price": 10 }, { "item": "z", "price": 10 } ], "footer": { "quantity_sum": 30 } }`

Here header and footer were displayed correctly but data was not.

2nd attempt:
`[ { "item": "x", "price": 10, "header": {"client_name": "x"} }, {  "item": "y", "price": 10 }, { "item": "z", "price": 10, "footer": { "quantity_sum": 30 } } ]`

Here I had to add header info to the first row of the table, and footer info to the last row of the table.

Please help me define the main JSON source structure, the docs are not very clear about this part.